# Does all strip lighting need lots of ventilation? I want to light inside this cabinet door.

Tags: electrical, lighting

[image][image] does all strip lighting need lots of ventilation? I want to light up inside a cabinet.

Comment: LED lights give off very very minimal heat. Look for LED STRIP CABINET lighting.

Comment: you can get strips that plug into USB, they are low power and usually produce plenty of light with no heat. you might already have an extra unused USB port on the TV or cable box.